# How to implement a search bar in flutter E-commerce app with tons of products?

Tags: android, ios, algorithm, flutter, dart

I've been developing an E-commerce app. It has a lot of products as of now and **more are being added every day**. I'm thinking of making a **list of thousands of products** (all of them) and do a **linear search**. Is there a better way to implement it. Suggest me some best practices. Thanks.

Comment: Use elasticsearch on backend and paging in client app with ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a package you can use [Flutter Search Bar](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_search_bar), personally I just use a second List and this simple function:

```
final List<String> filteredNames;
final List<String> names = [
  //your data or database
];

onChanged: (input) {
  input = input.toLowerCase(); //for no case-sensitive search
    setState(() {
      filteredNames = names.where((name) {
        var exName = name.toLowerCase();
        return exName.contains(input);
      }).toList();
   });
},
```

It's easy to implement but the downside is bad performance for very large lists (a few thousands should be working fine I think, try it out).

For handling search in really large lists check out [Stack Overflow-How to handle searching large lists in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043133/how-to-handle-searching-large-lists-in-flutter)

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you 