Flutter app hangs when parsing large input in custom CodeParser
I'm developing a Flutter application that uses a custom CodeParser to parse input and update a CoordinateSystemModel. The parser works fine for small inputs, but it hangs and becomes unresponsive when dealing with larger inputs. Here's a simplified version of my CodeParser:
class CodeParser {
  static void parseCode(String code, CoordinateSystemModel model) {
    print('Parsing code: $code');
    List<String> lines = code.split('\n');
    List<Place> newPlaces = [];
    List<Task> newTasks = [];

    for (String line in lines) {
      line = line.trim();
      parseAndExecuteLine(line, model, newPlaces, newTasks);
    }

    model.clearAndReplacePlaces(newPlaces);
    model.clearAndReplaceTasks(newTasks);
  }

  static void parseAndExecuteLine(String line, CoordinateSystemModel model,
      [List<Place>? newPlaces, List<Task>? newTasks]) {
    if (line.isEmpty) return;

    if (line.startsWith('project')) {
      _parseProject(line, model);
    } else if (line.startsWith('type')) {
      _parseType(line, model);
    } else if (line.startsWith('range')) {
      _parseRange(line, model);
    } else if (line.startsWith('path')) {
      _parsePath(line, model);
    } else if (line.startsWith('place')) {
      Place? place = _parsePlace(line);
      if (place != null) {
        if (newPlaces != null) {
          newPlaces.add(place);
        } else {
          model.addPlace(place);
        }
      }
    } else if (line.startsWith('task')) {
      Task? task = _parseTask(line);
      if (task != null) {
        if (newTasks != null) {
          newTasks.add(task);
        } else {
          model.addTask(task);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Other parsing methods...
}

The parser works fine with small inputs, but it hangs when I try to parse larger inputs.
I've tried optimizing the parser by implementing a chunked approach and adding batch methods to my CoordinateSystemModel:
void addPlaces(List<Place> newPlaces) {
  _places.addAll(newPlaces);
  _places.sort((a, b) => a.km.compareTo(b.km));
  _updateCodeAndNotify();
}

void addTasks(List<Task> newTasks) {
  _tasks.addAll(newTasks);
  _tasks.sort((a, b) => a.startDate.compareTo(b.startDate));
  _updateCodeAndNotify();
}

However, the app still becomes unresponsive with larger inputs. How can I optimize my CodeParser to handle larger inputs without hanging? Any suggestions for improving performance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
Environment:
Flutter 3.22.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b0850beeb2 (5 weeks ago) • 2024-07-16 21:43:41 -0700
Engine • revision 235db911ba
Tools • Dart 3.4.4 • DevTools 2.34.3
Browser: Google Chrome
OS: macOS

Consider using isolates for performing the workload off the UI thread. It won't go any faster, but at least it won't be blocking the user from interacting with the app. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043133/how-to-handle-searching-large-lists-in-flutter
